# Make List items selectable in edit mode, EditMode example from documentation not working

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I want to add the possibility to select items in a list when edit mode is selected, additionally to the delete and move option. Ideally I want to use the existing edit, delete and move buttons instead of writing my own. I tried the [example from the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editmode). It's not working for me. The value of `editMode` is always `.inactive`. I'm using XCode 14. The deployment target of my app is iOS 16.0.

This is my source code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode)
    private var editMode
    
    @State
    private var name = "Maria Ruiz"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                if editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing == true {
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                } else {
                    Text("test")
                }
            }
            .animation(nil, value: editMode?.wrappedValue)
            .toolbar { // Assumes embedding this view in a NavigationView.
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

It always shows the test text. I also tried a variant with the `.onChange` modifier, with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forwarding the fix from https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716434:

> Try extracting the parts that access the editMode property from the
> container that changes based on it, like `List`/`Form`.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                MyForm()
                
            }
            .toolbar { // Assumes embedding this view in a NavigationView.
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
struct MyForm: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode)
    private var editMode
    
    @State
    private var name = "Maria Ruiz"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(editMode!.wrappedValue.isEditing))
        
        if editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing == true {
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
        } else {
            Text("test")
        }
    }
}
```